# Can my Less CSS code be improved?

Tags: css, less-css

I just started getting into the Less CSS framework and I am wondering if I'm doing it right and how the code can be improved if possible.

**global.less**

```
//variables
@themeRed: #cc1111;
@themeColor: @themeRed;
@marginBottom: 10px;
@contentRadius: 5px;

//mixins
.border-radius(@args) {
  -webkit-border-radius: @args; 
  -moz-border-radius: @args; 
  border-radius: @args; 
}

//styles
body {
    font: 12px Arial;
    color: #333;
    background: #e9eaed;
}

a {
    &:link, &:visited {
        color: @themeColor;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    &:hover {
        border-bottom: solid 1px;
    }
    &:active {
        //color: lighten(@themeColor, 10%);
    }
}

#topbar {
    background: @themeColor;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
}

#container {
    width: 750px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

#header {
    display: table;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: @marginBottom;
    .wrapper {
        vertical-align: middle;
        display: table-cell;
        text-align: center;
    }
}

#sitename {
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px @themeColor;
    a {
        color: #fff;
        border: none;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
}

.section-heading {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: @marginBottom;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: @themeColor;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    line-height: 29px;
}

p {
    line-height: 1.5em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.last {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

#nav {
    position: absolute;
    width: 90px;
    text-align: right;
    margin-top: @contentRadius;
    li {
        border-right: 2px solid lighten(@themeColor, 30%);
        padding: 2px 5px 2px 0;
        margin-bottom: 2px;
        &:hover {
            border-color: @themeColor;
        }
        &.active {
            border-color: @themeColor;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    }
}

.content {
    width: 518px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: @marginBottom;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #e5e6e9 #dfe0e4 #d0d1d5;
    border-bottom: solid 2px @themeColor;
   .border-radius(@contentRadius);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px #d1d1d1;
    a {
        border-bottom: 0;
        &:hover {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
    }
}

#advertisement {
    margin-bottom: @marginBottom;
    .adsbygoogle {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}

#footer {
    text-align: center;
    p {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks just fine, I think. Only some really minor things come to mind

1. For `font-family`, it's good to always end with a generic font face style; in this case it'd be `sans-serif`. Arial is of course as "web-safe" as it gets, but still.
2. Why does `#nav` have a `position: absolute` rule, but no actual positioning (`left`, `top`, etc.) values? I imagine you're doing some JS positioning, but you should still have a fallback position (or just set `position: absolute` in the JS, so it's only there when needed).
3. You could consider using `:last-of-type` instead of explicitly giving elements a `last` class. Depends on [what browsers you're targeting](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3)
4. Remove the `a:active` rule; you've already commented it out of the code.
5. You may want to do a `box-shadow` function that does the vendor-prefix magic, similar to your `border-radius`
6. You have one `@themeColor`, but also a bunch of different hard-coded colors (e.g. border colors on `.content`). So while it's easy to change the `@themeColor`, you'll probably still have to go through and change every other color to better match the new theme. If you can, use the [color functions](http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-operations) to derive the rest of the palette from `@themeColor` or make a more comprehensive list of color variables (even if they're only used once, it's still nice to be able to define the whole color scheme in 1 place).